# How to fire OnSelectedIndexChanged of GridView using c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 grids, `grid1` and `grid2`.

`grid2` will be filled based on which row is clicked in `grid1`. I have done it by binding `OnSelectedIndexChanged` of `grid1`.

But at page load the `grid2` will be empty as no row selection is made.
So I was planning of firing the row selection of `grid1` using c# code so that both grids will be having data at page load.

I have started coding like.

```
            grid1.DataSource = versions.DefaultView;
            grid1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            grid1.DataBind();
```

But the event is not firing.
Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the method programmatically.

```
grid1.DataSource = versions.DefaultView;
grid1.SelectedIndex = 0;
grid1.DataBind();

grid1_SelectedIndexChanged(grid1, new EventArgs());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the event on `Page_Load` because you already know what the selected index of the first grid should be. The event is needed after user interaction with the page. Just `DataBind()` the second grid on `Page_Load` which data corresponding to the 0 selected index of the first grid the same way that you databind the first grid.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    grid1.DataSource = versions.DefaultView;
    grid1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    grid1.DataBind();
    DataBindGridByIndex(0);
}
else
{
    grid1.DataSource = versions.DefaultView;
    grid1.DataBind();
}

public void DataBindGridByIndex(int index)
{
    // Logic to databind second grid by selected index.
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.I though of it before. can in any way I could fire OnSelectionIndexChanged

Comment: @Robert_Junior You cannot on initial load. In order for the event to be fired a postback needs to be triggered and then post data is read and events are raised. You can however call the event handler from within the page load code.